# PHP library in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Where should I upload my PHP library in WP?

I have this library which I want upload into my WP and acess it from my functions.php

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I have downloaded it into wp-content folder, but I may have wrong path in my code? How should I solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. Depending on where you'd use it, the method of calling this library can be different accordingly.

As @Kirk mentioned in the comment on your question, create a custom plugin. [Tutorial here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/) and include your library in the custom plugin and all your depending code as well.

Let's say your plugin directory structure is like this:

```
- custom-plugin
- - lib
- - - simplehtmldom.php
- - custom-plugin.php
```

What I did there is put the PHP library file in a directory called `lib` and then we can include it in `custom-plugin.php` or wherever you need it.

```
include 'lib/simplehtmldom.php';
```